# Explanation of different Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Bin folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`, I see a number of different folders. I could not understand what some of them are for:

Specifically `amd64_x86` and `x86_amd64`. How can you have both `x86` and `amd64` "together"? And what is the meaning of them in different order?

Also, can I assume that the root folder (i.e. `VC\Bin\`) is for `x86`?

(I was specifically looking for the `cl.exe` file.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These subdirs contain *cross compilers*.  They run on one architecture and produce code for another.  Three architectures are supported, x86 (32-bit Intel/AMD), amd64 (64-bit Intel/AMD, aka x64) and arm.  So:

- x86_amd64: contains a 32-bit compiler and linker that generate x64 code.  Could be useful on a build server that boots a 32-bit operating system.
- amd64_x86: contains a 64-bit compiler and linker that generate x86 code.  Can be useful to tackle very large source code files that make a 32-bit compiler run out of memory.  Not the kind of code that a human ever writes, but not unlikely to go wrong with auto-generated code.
- x86_arm and amd64_arm: respectively a 32-bit and 64-bit compiler that generate ARM code.  Note how targeting an ARM device always requires a cross-compiler.  Also the reason there are no arm_x86 and arm_amd64 subdirs, your dev machine doesn't have an ARM processor.

Use the [Developer Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx) to setup an environment to run cl.exe by hand.

Comment: I'm confused by my own experimenting with 64-bit intel cpu + 64-bit Win8.1 os + 32-bit MSVS 2015 IDE installed into \program files (x86)\ folder. Experiments are: 1-Build target 32-bit (x86) => VS checks VC\bin folder for cl.exe. 2-) Build target 64-bit (x64) => VS checks VC\bin\x86-amd64 folder. So my *host* is a 64-bit architecture, but IDE (being 32-bit) considers it as an 32-bit x86 architecture, and uses x86 to x64 cross compiler when I want to build 64-bit code on my 64-bit host. So in your answer the **architecture** for host could be replaced by IDE being 32-bit / 64-bit ? Confusion ?

Comment: The following folders exist on MSVS v14.0\VC\bin location:  1-) bin\  , 2-) bin\amd64, 3-) bin\x86-amd64, 4-) bin\amd64-x86... So what about *bin\amd64* folder ? under which condition could my IDE use it ? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > "Executable Directories" setting.  VS2015 is getting old, probably just easier to upgrade.  VS2019 and up now use the 64-bit compiler by default.